# Can you create Outlook 2010 rules based on content or formatting?

Tags: formatting, automation, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

This is not a critical issue, but it's something I'd like to accomplish. I'm also not sure that rules are the way to go, but I'm looking for something fully automated.

I have a correspondent who insists on typesetting his e-mails in Comic Sans. This offends my delicate sensibilities to no end. What I'd like is some automated tool in Outlook that detects the offending font and automatically switches that formatting to *almost anything else.* (If I can change the target font, great, if it just converts that e-mail to plain text, great. My preference would be Calibri, but again, whatever, as long as it isn't Comic Sans.) I'd like to do this *without* losing formatting on all e-mails. I don't need to go nuclear here, a surgical strike is exactly what's needed.

Like I said, I'm not sure Outlook rules are the place for this, as those are mostly for filing. (And I've stopped using them as they were creating some maintenance hiccups on my phone.) Even if it's just a macro I'd write, something, that checks the inbox item, looks for Comic Sans, and removes/changes the formatting.

Any help?

Comment: Lame suggestion of the day: you could just delete the Comic Sans font from your system. Most applications (including Outlook) handle font substitution reasonably well now. By doing this, you'll never have to look at Comic Sans in any context! Seriously, though: I was sure Outlook had an option to convert incoming HTML message text to plain text per user, but can't find it in Outlook 2007. :(

Comment: @boot13: I've considered it, believe me! And I thought so, too, but I can't find it in 2010 either ...

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle around the `HTMLBody` property. You want a rule that runs a script to do something like:

```
Public Sub RemoveFont (email as MailItem)
   email.HTMLBody = Replace (email.HTMLBody, "Comic Sans MS", "Calibri")
End Sub
```

That might be a bit too simplistic depending on the complexity of the emails, but the general gist is about right, I think.

Comment: Any way to get that to automatically run on receipt from a given sender?

Comment: Just set up the rule using a "from people or distribution list" condition. I've only got 2007 at work, I'll check 2010 when I get home to make sure there's no difference.